# How to subtract years from sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle

What would be the expression to check if someone's 20 years or over without hard-coding the date?

In the SQL

```
 SELECT student_fname 
 FROM students
 WHERE dob<'05-MAR-1995';
```

I was thinking about using `SYSDATE` but then I don't know the syntax to subtract 20 years.

Comment: sysdate - interval '20' year

Comment: Note that subtracting intervals can be problematic.  If your `sysdate` is a Feb 29, subtracting a number of years will fail if the resulting year is not a leap year.  Now, in this case, since you're subtracting a multiple of 4, you're safe until 2120 which is probably good enough.  If you were to subtract a different interval, though, you might have issues.

Comment: This is a very remote posibility, but can happen, i think is better using add_months:)

Comment: For 20 years, you can do `sysdate - 20*365.25`.  This will also work until 2120.  Of course, Justin's answer is better.

Comment: @Justin Cave -- When you say 'fail' do you mean error and die or just give you say the 28th instead of 29th?  I'm not overly familiar with oracle I confess I've used mysql much more heavily and it just converts 29 to 28 which for all my purposes seems to be sufficient.

Comment: @UncleIroh, it fails as per the ANSI standard. If MySQL doesn't fail in such a case with an interval, it doesn't adhere to the ANSI standard.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, this gives fractional values, better use `TRUNC(sysdate - 20*365.25)`. Of course `ADD_MONTH()` is the best solution.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
WHERE dob < add_months( trunc(sysdate), -12*20 );
```

would work assuming that you want to ignore the time component of `sysdate`.

Comment: I realize this post is old but can you tell me what the `*20` part means?

Comment: @Mike-SMT - The goal was to subtract 20 years.  `add_months` adds (or subtracts) months so this subtracts 12*20 months to subtract 20 years.

Comment: Ah I must have missed that part.

Comment: Also works for leap years!

Answer (score 7):

In Oracle the [NUMTOYMINTERVAL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/NUMTOYMINTERVAL.html) function is designed precisely for this usecase, eg

```
SELECT SYSDATE - NUMTOYMINTERVAL(20, 'year') FROM dual;
```

Comment: This throws an error if SYSDATE is 29th of february whereas add_months() does not. For other purposes it is clean.