# How can I filter for CURRENT_DATE / SYSDATE - 2 years?

Tags: date, exasolution

I have a table t with a column "date" which has the type "DATE":

```
date
2018-10-01
2019-02-03
2020-01-01
2021-01-01
```

I want to get only entries where CURRENT_DATE / SYSDATE minus 2 years is true. So the result should be (CURRENT_DATE / SYSDATE = "2021-05-01":

```
date
2019-02-03
2020-01-01
2021-01-01
```

My code:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE YEAR(t.date) >= ADD_YEARS(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE), -2)
```

But that gives me the error

> Feature not supported: Incomparable Types: DECIMAL(4,0) and DATE!

Using SYSDATE with

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE YEAR(t.date) >= ADD_YEARS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -2)
```

gives the error

> Feature not supported: Incomparable Types: DECIMAL(4,0) and DATE!

I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/28888880/4435175 with

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE YEAR(t.date) >= add_months( trunc(sysdate), -12*2 )
```

but that gave me the same error

> Feature not supported: Incomparable Types: DECIMAL(4,0) and DATE!

Comment: use datediff(), dont use Year(date)

Answer (score 1):

`sysdate` already returns you date. No need to trunc it.

Looks like something is wrong with data type of column `t.date`.

What `describe t;` shows you?

**UPD.**

I see 2 options here. First one is more preferable for me, as it doesn't apply function to every `t.date` value.

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE t.date >= add_years (sysdate, -2)
--WHERE years_between (sysdate, t.date) >= 2
```

Comment: Forgot that I use YEAR(t.date) >=, edited my code.

DESCRIBE shows `SQL_TYPE DATE` for column "date"